# Rebuild lucene index after publishing issue

Tags: indexing, lucene

I have an issue related to the lucene index. The index is not being built when I do smart publish even if there is onPublishEndAsync added, but it does when I do republish.

```
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync"/>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the item you changed is ending up in the `web` database?

Comment: Also, what version of Sitecore are you using? Can you add some more details about your environment (is this a CD server, a combined CM/CD, are there any custom search configs, etc.)?

Comment: Smart Publish doesn't actually publish the item unless there is an actual change (in revision). You need to full publish it to ensure a reindex.

Comment: Mark Cassidy, there is a change already

Comment: Dan Sinclair, yes the change is on web DB.
I have combined CM/CD. There are no custom search configs.
Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170407)

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue, it's the expected behavior.

The thing is that the **smart publish won't publish anything** if there isn't any change since the last publish you did.

The **republish however will publish every single item** on the master no matter what.

That's why you can see the elements being (re)created on the web index when republishing but can't see anything happening when smart publishing.

You can find more information about the different way of publishing something in Sitecore on this SSE post: [What is the difference between republish, smart publish and incremental publishes?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-is-the-difference-between-republish-smart-publish-and-incremental-publishe).

Comment: There is a change already.